# I was able to run the application without any problems yesterday, but today I get this error

Tags: python, flask, web-applications

I created an application using Python, Flask and MySQL, but now I get this errors every time I point my browser to localhost: 8080 . I don't know exactly what kind of mistake to find, can one of the html pages contain an error? Or it is related only to the code in the application?

> "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
>
> "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
import mysql.connector

mydb= mysql.connector.connect(
     host= "localhost",
     user="aplicatieuser",
     password="1234",
database="aplicatie"
)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/showHome')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')


@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        if _name and _email and _password:
       conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            cursor.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_hashed_password))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            if len(data) == 0:
                conn.commit()
                return json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
            else:
                return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

     @app.route('/showSignin')
def showSignin():
    return render_template('signin.html')

@app.route('/showTodo')
def showTodo():
    return render_template('todo.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080)
```

Comment: This Code 404 is when cant access to the file on the net. Try to make sure your image.ICO is present in the / directory. File names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a route defined for the root "/".
So change:

```
@app.route('/showHome')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

To:

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Or use: http://localhost:8080/showHome in your browser.